# How to find the green slime in Slime Rancher?

Tags: slime-rancher

In the game Slime Rancher there are many types of slime, however there is a slime which I have not yet discovered, though I know its plort is green, and on the [Slime Rancher website](http://slimerancher.com/) there is a picture of it:

[image]

However I have no idea what it is called, nor where to find it, and I have tried Googling it, but even the Wikia Slime list doesn't contain it so I have been unable to find it. So, what is it called and where can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Rad Slimes](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/wiki/Rad_Slime) can be found in [The Indigo Quarry](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Indigo_Quarry).**

They were added to the game on April 13, 2016 with the aptly named Indigo Quarry Update ([v0.3.0](https://slimerancher.gamepedia.com/Version_0.3.0))*.

> **Rad Slimes** are Slimes found exclusively in [The Indigo Quarry](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Indigo_Quarry). Unlike other Harmful Slimes they do not deal damage directly, but when exposed to their aura for long enough Beatrix will start taking constant damage as long as she remains within the aura.
>
> [image: Rad Slimes]

<sup>Excerpt and photo from [*Slime Rancher Wikia*](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/wiki/Rad_Slime)</sup>

<sub>*Rad Slimes were obtainable in earlier versions of the game, but were unobtainable for versions between v0.2.0 and v0.3.0.</sub>

Comment: While correct, I can't help but feel this answer is pretty useless at this point.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer why do you feel it is useless?

Comment: @Ash Because it's not what the question was asking. When the question was asked, the slimes were featured on the game's websites, but were not available in game. As soon as they were introduced, the entire premise of the question fell, so answering the question as if it was asked today is not useful.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer This question still recieves a large amount of traffic from google search results. The accepted answer gave the misleading impression that these slimes were still only obtainable through console commands.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I disagree - updating answers when games change is a good thing - because otherwise people might still think they need to use console commands, if they've not been to whatever location in the game that they are actually found in.

Comment: @Ash Cool, go ahead and upvote.

Answer (score -1):

It's on the Slime wiki, it's called a [Rad Slime](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/wiki/Rad_Slime). As of v 0.2.2 they are not yet in the game.

Comment: They have now been implemented in the game and an answer has been posted and accepted stating this and fully answering the question, so please either [edit] your answer and somehow make it better than the already existing answers, or please delete it -- this question is cluttered up enough as it is with useless and now obsolete answers like this.

Answer (score -1):

The green slime is called "Rad Slime". It has not yet been added to the game, but, by using commands you can spawn it. The Rad Slime emits some radiation because of which you cannot stay too long near them. On the [slime wikia](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/wiki/Slimes) it says it will be added in the quarry area that you can currently reach by using the jetpack. Now, there are just some hens and angry [largos](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/wiki/Rad_Slime).

Comment: Which commands exactly can you use to spawn them?

Comment: Aaand they're in the game now.

Answer (score -1):

This slime is called a Rad slime they are also called Raddies according to the slime rancher wiki rad slimes will spawn in the indigo quarry. The Rad slime is not yet implemented but will be added in a later version.[Here's the slime rancher wiki link](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/wiki/Slime_Rancher_Wikia)

Comment: They have now been implemented in the game so as this answer is now obsolete and doesn't really add much more than any of the other answers please consider deleting it as this question is pretty cluttered already with answers almost identical to each other (apart from now the now accepted answer).